# What rank must I achieve for Hockey Ultimate Team Pro monthly playoff in NHL '12?

Tags: achievements, nhl-12

In NHL '12, I am trying to complete the last achievement for getting into a Hockey Ultimate Team playoff tournament. I have completed the Amateur and Elite ranks, but do not know the general ranking area I need to make the Pro tourny.  Does anyone have experience with this or know the general range I should aim for?